# TextViews invisible inside LinearLayout?

Tags: android, xml, android-listview, android-linearlayout

I have some `TextView`s inside a `LinearLayout`. At runtime, the `LinearLayout` is visible, but none of the `TextViews` are. Here is the XML:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5384615384615385"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true">
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/onezero"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="one"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="17dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:clickable="true" />
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/oneone"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="two"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:layout_margin="17dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:clickable="true" />
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/onefour"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="three"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:layout_margin="17dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:clickable="true" />
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/other"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="four"
            android:layout_margin="17dp"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:clickable="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ScrollView 
        android:id="@+id/scrollview1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:typeface="sans"
            android:textSize="17sp" 
            />

    </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

How do I make them visible?

EDIT: Code that accesses this layout:

```
void fragment(){
                ten.setTextColor(0xFFFFFF);//These are the 4 TextViews
        eleven.setTextColor(0xFFFFFF);
        fourteen.setTextColor(0xFFFFFF);
        other.setTextColor(0xFFFFFF);

            ten.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            eleven.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        fourteen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        other.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Code where I am initializing the textviews:

```
ten=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.onezero);
eleven=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.oneone); 
fourteen=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.onefour);
other=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.other);
```

**EDIT:** I tried clicking on the LinearLayout area and the TextViews are registering clicks.. that means that they are there but invisible...

Comment: I ran your code.. its working fine... Can u show the code that accesses this view to the activity?

Comment: +1 @amal, views are visible

Comment: @vergilcorleone set the background color of your framelayout to red and see if the framelayout itself is showing at all.

Comment: @Su-AuHwang Hi, I set the `TextView`s' background to red, now they are visible as red rectangles, but no text is visible inside them, additionally, they are registering clicks, that means the text is present, but somehow invisible .

Comment: Everything is fine with your code.. just see my edit in my answer

Answer (score 2):

The color you are applying is white...

```
 0xFFFFFF
```

try changing the color to contrast with your layout color..

Edit:

Its took a long time for me to realize this.. try it with the following code:

```
 textview.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#bdbdbd"));
```

Comment: My layout color is black, so white should be visible.

Comment: okay.. can u show us more code..the code snippet where u are calling the non java resources using findviewbyid.

Comment: I tried clicking on the LinearLayout area and the TextViews are registering clicks.. that means that they are there but invisible...

Comment: I changed background color of textviews to red, now red rectangles are visible, but no text visible in them..

Comment: I added the answer below. Using `Color.WHITE` instead of the hex worked.

Answer (score 0):

Change your layout with this prefixes

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

**or**

In FrameLayout `android:layout_height="0dp"` this will make the view invisible, probably intended for layout_width should be `wrap_content`

Comment: This layout I posted is only a small snipped from a bigger layout.

Comment: if it so? then post all the code that will help to solve your problem.

Comment: as of your code now i was updated answer look at that. still not solved you have to show full xml code.

Comment: No, I am using weights, so framelayout's width is supposed to be 0dp.

Comment: then you have to show that remaining xml code also. i run your code it's showing all the textviews properly.

Comment: The rest of the layout is very complex, and is connected to the java code a lot, it will just confuse people. I really don't think this problem is because of the rest of the layout because the `FrameLayout`  I posted is isolated..

Comment: I tried clicking on the LinearLayout area and the TextViews are registering clicks.. that means that they are there but invisible...

Answer (score 0):

you are using android:layout_weight - ratio based space distribution. To make it work you have to set:

android:layout_width="0dp"

Comment: I did that, still they are not visible.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

And then change your text color in java class

use

```
000000
```

instead

```
0xFFFFFF
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You have not assigned the layout_height of your parent layout i.e. FrameLayout. Try this:

<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.5384615384615385"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/onezero"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="17dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="one"
                android:textIsSelectable="true"
                android:typeface="sans" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/oneone"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="17dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="two"
                android:textIsSelectable="true"
                android:typeface="sans" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/onefour"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="17dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="three"
                android:textIsSelectable="true"
                android:typeface="sans" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/other"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="17dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="four"
                android:textIsSelectable="true"
                android:typeface="sans" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollview1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:typeface="sans" />
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, using hex codes for colors in:

```
    ten.setTextColor(0xFFFFFF);//These are the 4 TextViews
    eleven.setTextColor(0xFFFFFF);
    fourteen.setTextColor(0xFFFFFF);
    other.setTextColor(0xFFFFFF);
```

doesn't work. I switched the `0xFFFFFF` with `Color.WHITE`:

```
    ten.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);//These are the 4 TextViews
    eleven.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    fourteen.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    other.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```

This works perfectly.

**EDIT:** Figured out why the hex codes didn't work. We need to attach a transparency hex at the beginning of every hex. For example if you want the colors to be 80% opaque, here's how to find the transparency hex:

```
255 * 0.8 = 204
```

Now convert 204 to hex( using google), you'll get `0xCC`. Add this before the hex code, and you'll get `0xCCFFFFFF`. Using this makes it work perfectly.